# In an accelerating reference frame, does the angular acceleration of a rolling wheel change?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-kinematics

Consider a rolling, perfectly circular wheel moving forwards with a translational acceleration $a$ in some inertial frame. It's a well-known fact that the angular acceleration of this wheel is $$\alpha=\frac{a}{R}$$ Now, let's shift into a frame accelerating with the wheel with an acceleration $A$. The new acceleration of the wheel is then just $a-A$, as can be verified by differentiating the velocity-addition formula. However, this implies that the angular acceleration changes, to $$\alpha'=\frac{a-A}{R}$$ This implies that if I move in a frame where $A=a$, I would observe the wheel to not be rotating at all! This is a bit unintuitive to me; is my reasoning and answer correct?

Answer (score 1):

First, in an inertial frame. The equation for the angular acceleration is obtained from the fact that the wheel is rolling without slipping. If the velocity of the contact point A is 0 we can get the angular velocity from the velocity of the center G

$$
\vec{0}=\vec{v}_A=\vec{v}_G+\vec{\omega}\times\overrightarrow{GA}=(v_G+\omega R)\vec{\imath}
$$

that gives

$$
\omega=-\dfrac{v_G}{R}
$$

The minus sign because if the wheel advances the rotation is clockwise.

Differentiating this equation we get

$$
\alpha=-\frac{a_G}{R}
$$

Now in a non inertial frame that is moving but not rotating, the center of the wheel is moving with acceleration

$$
a'_G = a_G - A
$$

but now the point A of contact with the floor is not at rest. It's moving backwards, with acceleration -A, and speed -At. So the equation for the no slip condition is

$$
-At\vec{\imath}= (v'_G+\omega R)\vec{\imath}
$$

and that gives

$$
\omega = \frac{v'_G+At}{R}
$$

and differentiation gives

$$
\alpha = \frac{a'_G +A}{R} = \frac{a_G}{R}
$$
the same as in the inertial frame.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a simpler problem. For the same rolling without slipping wheel you have
$$\omega = \frac{v}{R}$$
Now if things were as you say then you can move with the wheel and would expect to see the wheel to be not rotating. But of course that doesn't happen if you've ever looked outside of a car at the wheels of a co moving car.

The $v$ in the equation for angular velocity (and the $a$ in your equation) are all measured relative to the ground frame, not relative to any arbitrary frame. If you're having difficulty thinking how a frame would be considered at rest with respect to a ground frame, then remember that the rolling without slipping equations $\omega = v/R$ (and hence $\alpha = a/R$) works only when there is friction. So  if there is an object that is stationary on the ground and there is no frictional force between the ground and that object, then any frame in which that object is stationary can be considered to be a ground frame.

Comment: I see. So, say the ground itself was moving; you would calculate $\alpha$ with respect to the ground frame, and then you could transform the linear acceleration as you pleased by frame switching, but the angular acceleration remains the same?

Comment: Yes. When you switch frames the acceleration of the center of mass might change but angular acceleration would depend on the acceleration of center of mass with respect to the ground frame.